# no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')

Tags: dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cluster)

df <- mtcars
```

When I am trying this code in Shiny I am getting the below error:

> Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

This is the code:

```
  gap_stat <- clusGap(df, kmeans, nstart=25, K.max=10)      
  km.res <- kmeans(df, maxSE(gap_stat$Tab[,"gap"], gap_stat$Tab[, "SE.sim"]), nstart=25)
  dfclust <-as.numeric(km.res$cluster)
  km_out <- df %>% mutate(cluster=dfclust)

 print(km_out)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, it runs fine for me